# How to modify program to include a reusable library?

Tags: c#, class-library

Instructions:

1. Print out the numbers from 1 to 100. If the number is divisible by 3, print "Fizz" instead. If by 5, print "Buzz." If by both, print "FizzBuzz."
2. Modify your program so that you have a program and a reusable library for rendering FizzBuzz.

I'm having a problem getting #2, as I'm not familiar with using C# class libraries. How do I modify my program so that I have a reusable library for rendering FizzBuzz?

This is what I have for #1:

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] fizzBuzz = new int[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    { 
        fizzBuzz[i] = (i + 1);
        // Console.WriteLine(fizzBuzz[i]);
    }
    for (int ii = 0; ii < fizzBuzz.Length; ii++)
    {
        if ((fizzBuzz[ii] % 5) == 0 && (fizzBuzz[ii] % 3) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FizzBuzz");
        }
        else if ((fizzBuzz[ii] % 5) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Buzz");
        }
        else if ((fizzBuzz[ii] % 3) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fizz");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fizzBuzz[ii]);
        }
    } Console.ReadLine();
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Create a class library having method/logic to have a number as input and return the output as FizzBuzz if its divisible by both 5 and 3(Else return a blank string, validate in main method if its blank then go for other if blocks). After the library is made, reference it to your existing method and call the method from your new library.

Answer (score 3):

Add a new project to your Visual Studio solution of type [Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f3cye135(v=vs.110).aspx).

Move your class into that new project.  Rename your class to something other than Program, e.g. change

```
class Program
```

to

```
public class FizzBuzz
```

(make it public so that it is visible from your original project).

Add a reference in your original project to your new class library project.